# Unable to transfer libraries from Image folder of openblas into rootfs

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openblas, rootfs

I'm trying to build openblas with yocto in my 64 bit armv8 board. I was able to successfully build openblas with the bitbake recipe that i have with me. All the library files have been built into the image folder of openblas. I have also added openblas to my local.conf. But, when I gave -

```
bitbake core-image-weston
```

I'm unable to find those libraries anywhere in rootfs. What is missing here?? here's the openblas recipe.

**openblas_0.2.20.bb**

```
DESCRIPTION = "OpenBLAS is an optimized BLAS library based on GotoBLAS2 1.13 BSD version."
SUMMARY = "OpenBLAS : An optimized BLAS library"
AUTHOR = "Alexander Leiva <norxander@gmail.com>"
HOMEPAGE = "http://www.openblas.net/"
SECTION = "libs"
LICENSE = "BSD-3-Clause"

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "libgfortran"
DEPENDS += " make libgfortran"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=5adf4792c949a00013ce25d476a2abc0"

SRC_URI = "https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/archive/v${PV}.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "48637eb29f5b492b91459175dcc574b1"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "5ef38b15d9c652985774869efd548b8e3e972e1e99475c673b25537ed7bcf394"

S = "${WORKDIR}/OpenBLAS-${PV}"

FLOATABI = "${@bb.utils.contains("TUNE_FEATURES", "vfp", bb.utils.contains("TUNE_FEATURES", "callconvention-hard", " -mfloat-abi=hard", " -mfloat-abi=softfp", d), "" ,d)}"


def map_arch(a, d):
  import re
  if re.match('i.86$', a): return 'ATOM'
  elif re.match('x86_64$', a): return 'ATOM'
  elif re.match('aarch32$', a): return 'ARMV7'
  elif re.match('aarch64$', a): return 'ARMV8'
  return a

def map_bits(a, d):
  import re
  if re.match('i.86$', a): return 32
  elif re.match('x86_64$', a): return 64
  elif re.match('aarch32$', a): return 32
  elif re.match('aarch64$', a): return 64
  return 64

do_compile () {
  oe_runmake HOSTCC="${BUILD_CC} " \
                     CC="${TARGET_PREFIX}gcc ${FLOATABI} ${TOOLCHAIN_OPTIONS}" \
                     PREFIX=${exec_prefix} \
                     CROSS_SUFFIX=${HOST_PREFIX} \
                     ONLY_CBLAS=1 BINARY='${@map_bits(d.getVar('TARGET_ARCH', True), d)}' \
                     TARGET='ARMV8'
}

do_install() {
  install -d ${D}${libdir}
  install -d ${D}${libdir}/cmake
  install -d ${D}${libdir}/pkgconfig
  oe_runmake HOSTCC="${BUILD_CC}" \
                     CC="${TARGET_PREFIX}gcc ${TOOLCHAIN_OPTIONS}" \
                     PREFIX=${exec_prefix} \
                     CROSS_SUFFIX=${HOST_PREFIX} \
                     ONLY_CBLAS=1 BINARY='${@map_bits(d.getVar('TARGET_ARCH', True), d)}' \
                     TARGET='${@map_arch(d.getVar('TARGET_ARCH', True), d)}' \
                     DESTDIR=${D} \
                     install

  cp -r ${D}/usr/lib/* ${D}/usr/lib64/
  rm -rf ${D}/usr/lib
  rm -rf ${D}/usr/bin
}

RDEPENDS_${PN}-dev = ""
RDEPENDS_${PN}-staticdev = ""

FILES_${PN}-libs = "${libdir}/*"

FILES_${PN}     += "/usr/lib64"
FILES_${PN}-dev = "${includedir} ${libdir}/lib${PN}.so"

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "staticdev"
```

Comment: which packages exactly are you adding to the image? Which files are not found on the image? Have you checked that the packages actually contain the files you expect?

Comment: How are you adding `openblas` to `local.conf`?

Comment: @CleitonBueno: like this - 
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " openblas"

Comment: @level1 I'm thinking there's a BUG in the recipe: try commenting this out: 
`
# rm -rf $ {D}/usr/lib
# rm -rf $ {D}/usr/bin
`

Comment: @JussiKukkonen: openblas has libopenblas.a , libopenblas.so , and libopenblas_armv8p-r0.2.20.so in its image/usr/lib64 folder. I want to include this in my rootfs, that is, inside /usr/lib64 . which i'm unable to do.

Comment: @CleitonBueno: Then I get this below errors and warnings. It is unable to do do_package.

```
ERROR: openblas-0.2.20-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: openblas path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/openblas/0.2.20-r0/packages-split/openblas/usr/lib/libopenblas.so' [dev-so]
ERROR: openblas-0.2.20-r0 do_package_qa: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
```

Comment: @level1 look for the openblas work directory, in `tmp/work/your_platform/openblash/${PV}/temp/temp/log.do_package`.

It contains the details of how the package that is used for installation is created.

Comment: @CleitonBueno : Also it gives this following warning. 

`
WARNING: openblas-0.2.20-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: openblas: found library in wrong location: /usr/lib/libopenblas.so.0
openblas: found library in wrong location: /usr/lib/libopenblas_armv8p-r0.2.20.so
openblas: found library in wrong location: /usr/lib/libopenblas.so
openblas-dbg: found library in wrong location: /usr/lib/.debug/libopenblas_armv8p-r0.2.20.so [libdir]
`

Comment: I did a build here using `qemuarm64`, there was no error/warning but it was installed in `/usr/lib` and copied to rootfs.

I ignored the part that removes and moves `/usr/lib64`.

Comment: @CleitonBueno: yes. It installs in /usr/lib for me as well. do_install works, but, do_package doesn't happen for me. Could you please link your openblas recipe? Thanks.